# Spring as a glorified factory; is this acceptable?

Tags: java, spring

I just inherited a Java application and upon inspection of the code, I'm seeing what IMHO is a bastardization of the Spring framework.  You see, the Java team seems to have an aversion to interfaces, so we end up with things like this:

```
@Autowired
private SomeConcreteFinalClass _myField;
```

There's no Spring configuration, no bean defined, no chance that I can test the containing object in isolation.  This is essentially an annotation-based factory with the overhead of Spring.

Am I out-of-line, or is this like using an elephant gun to kill flies?  I just have to have a reality check since *everyone else on the team* thinks this is perfectly acceptable.

**Edit**
In many cases these annotated factories appear in complex processing classes that would benefit immensely from isolated testing.  The team also frowns upon testing though.

There's no mystery here, I hope.  If I have a concrete class, that's not behind an interface, and there's no corresponding Spring bean to "setup" the object, then it's inarguably a glorified factory that can be implemented with 10 lines of code.

Spring is not used in any other way in the system; this is it.

My goals right now:

- Institute a testing policy
- Educate
  the team on the virtues of component
  isolation
- Move these Autowired fields
  behind interfaces

I guess the final question is: is there any benefit to keeping these fields Autowired if we're not testing or in any other way utilizing the framework. I'd just as well `new` the object if the dependency is immutable.

Comment: Of course: an elephant gun is the weapon-of-choice to kill elephant-sized mutant flies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would agree with you that this is an abuse of what Spring can do (as opposed to what Spring SHOULD do). Is the person who designed the application this way around? It would be interesting to hear their justification for building an application this way.

Answer (score 4):

It's certainly limiting what is possible, but it's not a total waste of time either.

Since the type in question is `final`, it can't be mocked-up easily for isolated testing.

However, instances of that type may still be highly configurable through their properties. Using Spring to inject an instance that is properly configured at runtime simplifies the containing class immensely. The class can focus on its responsibilities, relying on Spring to provide it with the collaborators that it needs.

Interfaces *are* over used; this may be a response to that. I think that starting with final, concrete classes for many types, then using readily-available refactoring tools to extract interfaces later, when a specific need is identified, is a defensible position in many contexts.

Comment: If the type is final, there could be an interface for isolation for extensibility, and testability.  In many cases these annotated factories appear in complex processing classes that would benefit immensely from isolated testing.  They also frown upon testing.

Comment: "Frown on testing," eh? I'm afraid I can't speak in their defense there! ;)

Comment: @AngelO'Sphere: Since the type is `final`, common tools for creating mock objects can't be used to create a replacement. So, you are stuck doing full integration tests of the class and its dependencies rather than unit testing the class itself.

Comment: Erm, you replace the SomeConcreteFinalClass with your own mock implementation, and put it in front of the classpath?

Comment: @AngelO'Sphere: Yes, you could do that. You'd have to create the class by hand, which may or may not be a big deal. The thing is, when you avoid that sort of kludge, your system isn't just easier to test, it tends to be easier to maintain and evolve.

Comment: Well, as I don't know your system I can not judge if it is easier to maintaine. It is quite common to use test classes instead of the real ones in situations like yours. After all it makes the "original" code definitely seperated from test code and makes the unit tests more easy, because they do not need to mock single methods all the time. And you can use the original wirering ...

Answer (score 1):

I can't say that I entirely see the point. After all, it would likely be a few lines of code to wire up the system in a `main` method and you would then not have the dependency on Spring.

And yes, I agree that not injecting interfaces is a bit pointless. I tend not to do a huge amount of Unit testing but, even so, I would lose any flexibility in changing implementations later on (or having different implementations of classes in different deployments - e.g. integration testing).

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but I can't tell if this is an abuse of Spring based on the two lines of code that you posted and I doubt that anyone else can, either.

If you're complaining about the fact that the static type of that object is not an interface you might have a point.  But even that's hard to tell from that single line of code.  Is that really a service or repository class without an interface?  If so, I agree.  If not, I'd need to know more.

If your team frowns on testing, that's too bad.  I would have thought that one of the reasons for Spring would be to facilitate testing.

You might have a point, but I can't be sure from your original question.  Maybe you can edit in more detail.

If this is an example of how you communicate with your teammates, perhaps they'd be justified if they said that you didn't explain yourself very well.  Make sure that you aren't just out for self-aggrandization here.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  I generally provide enough detail so that experts in the area should be able to piece it together or ask for more detail.  The jab on my communication skills was a bit uncalled for, but +1 for highlighting the need for more detail.

Comment: "I generally provide enough detail" - not this time.  And only your teammates can give you meaningful feedback about whether your communication skills are sufficient.  Worry less about what I think and more about them.  I'd suggest that you consider getting it instead of assuming that they're wrong.